# Is it possible to call a network method in a Thread class from the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm curious whether or not it's possible to call a network process from the UI thread if the method called is in an instance of a Threaded class... pseudo...

```
class MyNetworkClass extends Thread{
    public boolean keepGoing = true; 
    public void run(){
       while(keepGoing);
    }

    public void doSomeNetworkStuff(){
      //do things that are illegal on the UI Thread
    }

}

//and then in my Activity...
MyNetworkClass mnc = new MyNetworkClass();
mnc.start();

mnc.doSomeNetworkStuff();
```

This feels totally illegal to me, but I'm wondering if it is in fact, and if so why?

Comment: Did you try it out? :)

Comment: Simon's comment is incorrect. You actually call the `mnc.doSomeNetworkStuff()` from the same thread as `mnc.start();`. This is presumably the UI thread but for sure not the thread which just started with `mnc.start`.

Comment: You can do it in an implicit way. I'd suggest to define `LinkedBlockingDeque` or similar, then `offer` a signal into the queue from UI thead, and call the queue's `poll` in infinite loop inside the new thread's `run` until it is not terminated. When `poll ` returns the signal you perform network action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually called the `mnc.doSomeNetworkStuff()` method from the same thread as `mnc.start();`.
This is presumably the UI thread, but for sure not the thread which just started with `mnc.start`;

Consider the situation:

```
//creates thread object - does not start a new thread yet
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {}
};
//...

thread.start(); //this actually started the thread
// the `run` method is now executed in this thread. 

//However if you called `run` manually as below
thread.run(); 
// it would be executed in the thread from which you have called it
// assuming that this flow is running in the UI thread, calling `thread.run()` 
// manually as above makes it execute in the UI thread.
```

EDIT:

Just to make things more clear. Consider that you have some static utility class like below:

```
public static class SomeUtilityClass {

    public static void someUtilityMethod(int i) {
        Log.i("SomeUtilityClass", "someUtilityMethod: " + i);
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your code, called from your "main" thread:

```
new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // 1.
        // call the utility method in new thread 
        SomeUtilityClass.someUtilityMethod(1);
    }
}.start();

// 2.
// call the same method from "main" thread 
SomeUtilityClass.someUtilityMethod(2);
```

Notice that `Thread#start()` exits immediately and you are not guaranteed which call to `SomeUtilityClass.someUtilityMethod();` will be executed first.

Comment: Right, I think the way to think of it accurately is to understand that the class that extends Thread isn't actually a separate thread, *except for the stuff in the `run` method. All the other methods are technically being called on the same thread as the one that grabbed the new instance of the Thread class.

Comment: Hi, just to make things more clear I added another example for your consideration in the answer.